# Convert UTC Datetime in MySQL Database To Clients Timezone without any libraries

Tags: javascript, mysql, time, utc, localdate

for about 3 days now im trying to convert a UTC Datetime for example (2020-04-18 13:41:18) to the clients time

For example for me it would be: 2020-04-18 15:41:18.

Output: Sat Apr 18 2020 13:41:18 GMT+0200 (Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit)

Im getting always the wrong time.

In the Database im using DateTime as datatype (MySQL) and storing this type of date: 2020-04-18 13:41:18

My Code is here:

```
let unixtime = Date.parse("<?php echo $publish_date ?>") / 1000; 

let publish_date = new Date(unixtime * 1000).toString();

document.write(publish_date);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You don't meed special librarys and i really don't undestand why it is a problem. see https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset  use that to add or subtract the time you want. the server has its own timezone, which you must also include the rest is math

Comment: The server automatically saves the datetime as UTC datetime so no specially timezone.

Comment: Look i gave you my answer hiow i have done it . You could also take a look at https://medium.com/@toastui/handling-time-zone-in-javascript-547e67aa842d

Comment: I already know this link. I know now all links related to javscript and date stuff. Im too stupid to implement this. Can you help me ?

Comment: Oh man. I still have no clue how to calculate the difference. He give me -120 and now???? @nbk

Answer (score 1):

This would show your unix time and add or subtract the users timezone in minutes

It uses the jkavascript sunction [getTimezoneOffset](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset)

```
let unixtime = Date.parse("<?php echo $publish_date ?>") / 1000; 

let publish_date = new Date(unixtime * 1000).toString();

var newDateObj = new Date();
newDateObj.setTime(date1.getTime() + (publish_date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000));

document.write(newDateObj);
```

You could also use the setTime to your published_date,but i don't know if you need the time any where else

Comment: Thanks! But I already found an other solution, which I will post.